# Can I have more than 1 private key in ~/.ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh-keys, private-key

I am trying to add an existing private key (`id_rsa` file) to my `~/.ssh` directory, but see that I already have one. Do I have to replace the existing key, or is there a way to combine them?

I assume there *must* be a way since it should be possible to have keys to different servers from the same user account...

Comment: I just store my keys in separate files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few options you can take here. In all options you would store the other key in its own file, /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa for these examples.

1) When you want to use a key other than ~/.ssh/id_rsa specify it with the -i argument `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.otherkey user@server.example.com`

2) If you want to use the key multiple times in your current session, add it to your ssh-agent with ssh-add: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.otherkey`

3) If you want to set this up more permanently you can specify the keys in ~/.ssh/config along the lines of:

```
Host shortcut
 HostName server.example.com
 User user
 IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.otherkey
```